# set a javascript variable to globally

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.buttonType = '';

  $("#inlineRadio8").click(function() {
    window.buttonType = 'checkbox';

  });

  $("#inlineRadio9").click(function() {
    window.buttonType = 'radio';
  });
});

document.write("<input type=window.buttonType name='inlineRadioOptions' id='inlineRadio1' value='Hockey'> ");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="chk2" id="inlineRadio8" value="val2" class="hidden" autocomplete="off">

<input type="radio" name="chk1" id="inlineRadio9" value="val1" class="hidden" autocomplete="off">
```

There are two button based on button click want to swap the input type.
i.e if this (#inlineRadio8) is clicked than input type should convert to checkbox else if inlineRadio9 is inovked then convert to radio type

This window.buttonType should be availble on the page i.e if i click inlineRadio8 button this variable should have value 'checkbox' if i click inlineRadio9 this should have the value 'radio'

how to achieve the same.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct , what issue are you getting

Comment: Define the variable outside of your document.ready ...

Comment: @hallleron `window.buttonType` is defined on the window scope, so it's already global

Comment: Your code works fine @AmanJoshi https://jsfiddle.net/m1hqz212/ you are having issues for other reason. Check your console for errors and add them to your question if they make no sense.

Comment: <script>
document.write("<input type='checkbox' name='inlineRadioOptions' id='inlineRadio1' value='Something'> ");</script>

I want to set dynamic input value but it says undefined window.buttonType value

Comment: @AmanJoshi Rewrite your question with the correct formatting and correct example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Updated please take a look

Comment: @AmanJoshi I rewrite your example for more readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need global variable for this. Just change the input type on the click.

Like :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inlineRadio8").on('click', function() {
    $("#inlineRadio1").prop('type', 'checkbox');

  });

  $("#inlineRadio9").on('click', function() {
    $("#inlineRadio1").prop('type', 'radio');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="chk1" id="inlineRadio8" value="val2" class="hidden" autocomplete="off">

<input type="radio" name="chk1" id="inlineRadio9" value="val1" class="hidden" autocomplete="off">

<input type='hidden' name='inlineRadioOptions' id='inlineRadio1' value='Hockey'>
```